# Penalty Box: why is the value of penalties so vague?

Tags: discussion, account-suspension

I just read about the [penalty box](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/). It says:

> If we think you are reachable, and the behavior is one that we feel
>   can change, we will try to warn you via email first when there are
>   behavior problems — so that we can address them before they become
>   deeper problems. But I make no guarantees; the community moderators
>   are very, very busy and there are a lot of things that need their
>   attention. The odds of moderators contacting you with a warning first
>   will be in direct proportion to how much evidence you’ve given us that
>   you are, in fact, a potentially valuable and contributing member of
>   the community.

I don't understand why Stack Overflow doesn't have something like "value of user fouls" in user's dashboard and "threshold of fouls" and "fouled activities" to help users understand how much their behavior is correct and which of their activities are bad, without needing moderator warnings.

I mean something like this:

> Your foul value: 60
>
> Threshold to reach penalty: 100

Maybe I don't understand anyway, what's your opinion?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm able to leave one comment here that puts my foul value at 1337 which make this whole *foul* graduation system kind of useless. [Be nice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240839/the-new-new-be-nice-policy-code-of-conduct-updated-with-your-feedback) is what you should invest in and that automatically rules out that there is room for *a bit of foul*.

Comment: It's also to prevent users from caring 0 for our rules up until they get to 99/100, stop with their behavior till they drop down, then go back to 99. If you show too much of a system it becomes gameable...

Comment: The numbers you're presenting are treated similarly like Q/A ban system, I'm sure that exact suspension mechanism/ratio is not fully open to public. That's intentionally apply to prevent anyone plays around certain threshold.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In most cases, the number of questions you have that have a negative score (and how negative it is) or are closed or deleted is your "foul value".

If you're engaging in other unwanted behaviour, such as posting abusive comments, it should be fairly obvious to you that you're not being nice at the time of posting, thus keeping you up to date on how often you've crossed the line doesn't seem particularly necessary.

The exact thresholds are hidden on purpose, because showing that allows users to game the system (not to mention that it may be based on many factors, and it's sometimes a manual instead of automatic process). **We want users to stop unwanted behaviour altogether**, not try to keep it below the punish-worthy threshold.

Answer (score 17):

> I don't understand why Stack Overflow doesn't have something like "value of user fouls" in user's dashboard and "threshold of fouls" and "fouled activities" to help users understand how much their behavior is correct and which of their activities are bad, without needing moderator warnings.

Because behavior problems cannot be quantified. Cheating is cheating no matter how hard you cheat, stealing content is stealing content regardless of whether you *meant* to steal, being rude/abusive is wrong no matter how you spin it. That said, every offense is evaluated on a case-by-case basis, because every user and every situation is different.

And besides, most users *don't* need us telling them what not to do, because they know that cheating, stealing and being rude/abusive are wrong.